# select tag in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a drop down menu and assign an onchange event on it in rails3. how would I do that.

```
<select name="" class="wy_inputs_selects sround">
       <% @domains.each do |record| %>
  <option value="<%= record.name %>.<%= record.tld %>" ><%= record.name %>.<%= record.tld %></option>
           <%end%>
</select>
```

I am converting the above code into ruby like

```
<%= select_tag "",:class=>'wy_inputs_selects sround',options_from_collection_for_select(@domains,"name",
```

But I am stuck with how to get the record.tld and record.name using the above format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<select name="" class="wy_inputs_selects sround">

<% @domains.each do |record| %>
 <% @name_tld = record.name.to_s + "." + record.tld.to_s %>
 <option value="#{@name_tld}" ><%= @name_tld %></option>
 <% end %>

</select>
```

you can also you the rails select helper method like so (this is used inside a form)

**example 1**

```
<%= form_for @dates,:remote => true do |f| %>
    <%= f.date_select :booking_date,:onchange => "this.form.submit();" %>
<% end %>
```

**example 2 (with default value)**

```
<%= form_for(@image),:remote => true do |f| %>
    <%= f.select :album_id, @albums_all.map {|m| [m.name, m.id] }, :selected => @album_id %> <!-- default value, current album -->
<% end %>
```

remember to include this in your views/layouts/application.html.erb file, so rails will use ajax

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

Comment: SO can I assign the onchange event handler to select tag like {:onchange => "show_spinner('"+"#{record.domainkey}"+"');"}

Comment: yes you can use it like this, `select_tag :variable, options_from_collection_for_select(:all, :id, :name), :onchange => 'your_onchange_handler()'` (please vote if it helps :) )

Comment: so wot does this :all :id and :name variables contain??I was trying to write the above code as <%= select_tag "",:class=>'wy_inputs_selects sround',options_from_collection_for_select(@domains,"name") But got stuck with these options

Comment: How can I implement the above code in ruby using select_tag :variable, options_from_collection_for_select(:all, :id, :name), :onchange => 'your_onchange_handler()'.. I am just learning ruby. Please help

Comment: Basically I am trying to implement <%= select_tag "",:class=>'wy_inputs_selects sround',options_from_collection_for_select(@domains.collect|records|,[records.name.records.tld,records.name.records.tld]))

Comment: do you want to populate a drop down list in rails3 ? if so you can use the rails f.select helper method

Comment: <%= form_for(@image) do |f| %>

Answer (score 0):

I would define the name in the model for record (record.rb or domain.rb, whatever the name of your model is), something like:

```
def detail_name
  return self.name+'.'+self.tld
end
```

Then call the detail_name from within the select tag.

Comment: In my controller I have done as @domains = Domains.by_userid(:key => session[:wy_main_userid]).So @ domains would contain name and tld values which I need to get in select tag in view page.